# sql(postgres)- How to create a trigger that multiply two rows from a table and add them a row in another table?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have two tables OrderItem and Orders. I wanted to update totalamount row in Orders table for every insert on OrderItem by multipying quantity and unitprice. However I couldn't create the right trigger. How can I create the trigger. Thanks in advance!

here is my Orders table:

```
      CREATE TABLE public.orders
(
  orderid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('orders_orderid_seq'::regclass),
  ordernumber integer NOT NULL,
  customerid integer NOT NULL,
  totalamount numeric(12,4) NOT NULL,
  orderdate timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT orders_pk PRIMARY KEY (orderid),
  CONSTRAINT orders_fk FOREIGN KEY (customerid)
      REFERENCES public.customer (customerid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

and here is my Orderitem table:

```
 CREATE TABLE public.orderitem
(
  orderitemid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('orderitem_orderitemid_seq'::regclass),
  orderid integer NOT NULL,
  productid integer NOT NULL,
  unitprice numeric(12,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  quantity integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT orderitem_pk PRIMARY KEY (orderitemid),
  CONSTRAINT orderitem_fk_order FOREIGN KEY (orderid)
      REFERENCES public.orders (orderid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT orderitem_fk_product FOREIGN KEY (productid)
      REFERENCES public.product (productid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.orderitem
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Trigger: unitprice on public.orderitem

-- DROP TRIGGER unitprice ON public.orderitem;

CREATE TRIGGER unitprice
  AFTER INSERT
  ON public.orderitem
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.transferunitprice();
```

and the trigger function that I've tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.increment_totalamount()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    SELECT Orderitem.unitprice * Orderitem.quantity + Orders.totalamount 
            INTO NEW.totalamount
    FROM Orderitem, Orders
    WHERE Orders.orderid = NEW.orderid;

    RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I forgot to add trigger itself:

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_totalamount
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON public.orderitem
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.increment_totalamount();
```

Comment: Please post the DDL as text, not as images.

Comment: okay it's done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger is on the `orderitem` table so you need to call a regular update statement inside the trigger.

Something in the line of this should work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_order_price() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $update_order_price$
    DECLARE
        delta numeric(14, 2)
    BEGIN
        -- Work out the increment/decrement amount(s).
        IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            delta = NEW.quantity * NEW.unitprice;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            delta = NEW.quantity * NEW.unitprice - OLD.quantity * OLD.unitprice;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            delta = - OLD.quantity * OLD.unitprice;
        END IF;

        -- Update the order row
        UPDATE orders 
        SET totalamount = totalamount + delta
        WHERE id = OLD.orderid;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$update_order_price$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working with little changes. I haven't tried for Delete operations yet.